# search multiple strings in multiple strings

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, if-statement

I want to search if 'bit' or 'yit' is in a word of a line I have parsed and split. Also, in the same line but a different word I want to look for 'If' or 'yup'.

The whole code should be in one line.

```
line=line.split()
if ('bit' or 'yit') in line[0] or ('If' or 'yup') in line[-2] :
```

It doesn't execute when I use this code.

This is my input:

```
"bit2_2" -> 25;
"yup" -> "end4";
"yit" -> "yup69";
 25 -> 56;
```

Comment: why don't you also include the type of input you have

Comment: Every condition should be separate: `if ('bit' in line[0]) or ('yit' in line[0]) or ('If' in line[-2]) or ('yup' in line[-2])`.

Comment: This is because `('bit' or 'yit')` for example, evaluates to `True`, being that neither `bit` or `yit` are falsey.

Comment: I shared my input BlueRine

Answer (score 0):

The `or` operator was using wrong form, you was compare `str or str` before `in`.

You need understand [operator precedence](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html&ved=2ahUKEwjUoerQieriAhWUK7kGHT8WDjgQFjAKegQIARAB&usg=AOvVaw20xmig3bG9EQm1_XcCKiMh)

About your question, you can to use [`any` built in function python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any)

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
line=line.split()
if 'bit' in line[0] or 'yit' in line[0] or 'If' in line[-2] or 'yup' in line[-2] :
```